# Why does the SSD network need an specific input size?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

Usually before using an image as an input for the Single Shot Multibox Detector (SSD) the image gets cropped/warped into the desired input size. Wide images like the one of the KITTI dataset will get squeezed a lot and therefore lose some information. 
I am wondering why the Single Shot Multibox Detector needs a specific input size of 300x300/512x512. Wouldn't it be more efficient if the network was able process wide images without squeezing them as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

300x300/512x512 is not necessary.

SSD is fully convolutional (without fully connected layer), so it can be feed with vary size of image. But, with increasing the input size, computation increasing too.